# How to disable HAL @RepositoryRestResource links?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I'm using `@RepositoryRestResource` to quickly expose `@Entity` objects via `spring-data-rest`.

Question: is it possible to disable any `_links` `self` `href` links from the `json` response?

```
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "search" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/people/search"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
     [...]
```

Comment: Maybe you need to extend the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` configuration and have a look at `jsonSchemaConverter()` - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.html